# Find missing side?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that the hypotenuse is equal to the opposite side divided by the sine of the theta, but would the hypotenuse also be equal to the adjacent side divided by the cosine of the theta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible mnemonic is:$$\text{soh cah toa}$$

- $\text{soh} \implies \sin \theta = \frac{\rm opposite}{\rm hypotenuse}$
- $\text{cah} \implies \cos \theta = \frac{\rm adjacent}{\rm hypotenuse}$
- $\text{toa}\implies \tan \theta = \frac{\rm opposite}{\rm adjacent}$

From $\text{cah}$ we get: $$\cos \theta = \frac{\rm adjacent}{\rm hypotenuse}\implies \text{hypotenuse} = \frac{\rm adjacent}{\cos \theta}$$

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help! ${}{}$